# How can I resolve the ubuntu error on Laravel installation command?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

Laravel global installer is showing error on repository

Code used to install and error:

```
inurture@sandbox:~$ composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
Changed current directory to /home/inurture/.composer


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...
```

How can I resolve this temporary failure?

[image]

Comment: Is there composer.json in the root directory ?

Comment: Please try `composer config -g repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org` and then `composer self-update`. Then try to install laravel.

Comment: Some antivirus also blocks `composer` requests. So try yo disable it first if you have any installed.

Comment: @DhananjayKyada : No antivirus installed and now the self-updates showing some error [link](http://prntscr.com/ogn6ou)

Comment: @DhananjayKyada after changing permission for cache folder some other error is coming http://prntscr.com/ogna4k

Comment: @SyamkumarKK. Try with `root` user.

Comment: Same error or root also :  
`code` [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution`code`